# What is the difference in visibility modifiers inside private class?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Like in title. Why are any modifiers allowed inside private classes in the first place? The private class is not visible outside the file, so we cannot access them anyway. If the visibility matters inside such classes, which is the recommended one?

Comment: Related (same question about "package-private" classes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049718/what-is-the-use-of-having-public-methods-when-the-class-is-having-a-default-acce?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260467/public-methods-in-package-private-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your private class can still implement a public interface (or extend an accessible class).

Or maybe just override `toString`, `equals` or `hashCode` (all of which have to be public).

Comment: If i get it right, your point is that access modifiers exist in private class so you can implement / extend and the compiler wouldn't allow limiting the visibility of methods. But still, I cannot use such methods outside the file so all the methods / fields could be implicitly set to public (so there won't ever be limiting visibility)

Comment: Why cannot you use these methods outside of the file? You can have a private class implement `Comparator` or `Runnable` or `Collection` and return an instance of it from your method. Code calling that method can invoke  `compare` or `run` or `size` on your private class instance.

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but in my test, when a private class implements an interface, the complier won't allow me to use such method when I retreive the object in another file (The type Test.Nested is not visible)

Comment: The type `Test.Nested` is not visible, but you can type it as `Object` (or `Runnable` or whatever interface it has).  `Object x = test.methodReturnsMyPrivateInstance(); x.toString();`

Comment: @Please you can't access the type directly outside the containing class, no, but if you have `private class MyComparator implements Comparator<Me>` you can return an instance of that class from a `public Comparator<Me> createComparator()` method and the caller can assign the returned reference to a variable of type `Comparator<Me>`.

Comment: You guys are right, seems I did it wrong ;)
And as to new fields / methods (not the ones from iterface or super class), is there any difference there?

Comment: There is no point in making the "new" fields/method public. But it's not illegal either. (it might actually be useful for reflection or some tools like the ones @Evgeniy mentions)

Answer (score 1):

One difference: privateClass.getMethods will return only public methods

Another one: some tools, like JAXB, may be looking for public setter/getters

Comment: As to the second one, shouldn't such tools avoid private classes?

Comment: You can have a nested private class to deserialize xml data

Comment: So, should I set all the methods / fields to public, just because some tools might require it?

Comment: Only if you are going to use those tools, otherwise visibility makes no real difference